# Creating a standalone HTTP server to invoke a URL

Tags: python, ruby

I have written Ruby/Sinatra code and run it using the command `sudo ruby server.rb -o 1.2.3.4 -p 80`. The program listens on port 80, gets the `url` query parameter, invokes the URL and sends the response back.

I would like to do the same in Python. I can setup Apache2, integrate it with Python as CGI and then write a Python program. How would I setup a similar standalone server in Python, without working with Apache2? BTW, I am trying to mimic the [SSRF](https://www.hackerone.com/blog-How-To-Server-Side-Request-Forgery-SSRF) vulnerability in the code.

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'open-uri'

get '/' do
  format 'RESPONSE: %s', open(params[:url]).read
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a Flask app, see their hello tutorial:

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/factory/

with the below code.

```
import os, requests
from flask import Flask, request

def create_app(test_config=None):

    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    @app.route('/')
    def hello():
        url = request.args.get('url')
        response = requests.get(url)
        return "Response: " + response.text
    return app
```

Comment: thanks it worked - I have modified the program as there is a requests in python and request in Flask. To avoid confusion, I have included the entire program with the imports.